# Is Incinerator Clayton good or evil?

Tags: borderlands-2

Im about to do the quest where i have to find incinerator clayton as a quest sent by lilith so i decided to do some research on this guy.What lilith said was that they worshiped her as a god (the firehawk).It also states that he sends vault hunters on tasks,so that must mean he is an ally.

> Incinerator Clayton is the main NPC of the mission Cult Following: The Enkindling, although the mission is given by Lilith in Sanctuary. Clayton is the leader of a cult called Children of the Firehawk. The Children of the Firehawk worship Lilith as their god and seek ways to please her. Clayton will send Vault Hunters on tasks, which mainly involve setting the cult's members on fire, in attempts to please The Firehawk.

However people on websites have said that clayton was a boss.

Im stuck between opinions between what the borderlands has said and what people have said on the web.

I would want to be prepared as much as possible before engaging on this quest.

Is he good or evil?

Comment: Whether he's good or evil has no effect on the quests. Just play them and you'll see ;)

Comment: To answer your question he is a crazy cultist trying to cleanse the world of filth through fire simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part it's just a normal quest with no particular (non-story) surprises. I would just play through the missions normally but note there will be a boss fight at the last mission.

Major (sidequest) spoilers:

> At the end of the final quest here Incinerator Clayton orders a bunch of Sanctuary citizens to be killed for blasphemy (or something). Lilith puts her foot down on this but Clayton (and the rest of the Children of the Firehawk) betray you/Lillith and you have to kill him. He's not particularly hard, as far as bosses go.

Comment: I think he just wanted to sacrifice some dude. Also I wouldn't even call him a boss, more like a named enemy.

Comment: ahhhhh k that makes SENSE

Answer (score 1):

Incinerator Clayton is both a friendly NPC in the beginning and an enemy later.

Borderlands is an RPG only in a "*level up, assign skill point*" sense, not in a true "*decide what to do*". Decision-wise it is a simple shooter - just kill whatever has a red (blue and yellow) health bar, and anything with a green bar is *quote* friendly *unquote*.

No one is also going to attack you from behind in Borderlands - whatever plot twists and allegiance changes do happen, happen in an up-front dramatic way - like in cutscenes - that is hardly missable.

So "being prepared" to a quest *story* gives you nothing. Even the most evil character will be classified as ally while giving quests, and therefore will be immune to harm, and you will be timely notified of them becoming evil and targetable.

Comment: but being prepared allows you to gather up effective weapons against the enemy.Such as corrosive damage for armour.

Comment: @sgsf That's why I said "being prepared for quest story". Combat-wise, of course, there are things to consider (not in this quest, though - it has normal bandits and spiderants with an occasional fire immune).

Comment: .. or in my case (I saw the twist coming), I had the sniper rifle out and his head in sights waiting for the healthbar color change. :)